# Prevent org mode from checking if file exists in external link

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to open pdf files in specific folder using org mode. 
For example, in a org file `test.org`:

```
My sample org file. Here is an external link: file:test.pdf
```

When I click on the link, it should open the file `/home/hakon/my_pdf_files/test.pdf`.

I have tried this: I added the following to my Emacs init file:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (setcdr (assoc "\\.pdf\\'" org-file-apps) "/home/hakon/my_org_pdf_viewer.sh %s")))
```

Where the shell script `my_org_pdf_viewer.sh` is:

```
#! /bin/bash

file_name=$(basename $1)
evince ~/my_pdf_files/"$file_name"
```

However this only works if the file name in the external link in `test.org` : `file:test.pdf` also exists as file name in the same folder as `test.org`, which is usually not the case. If the file does not exist in that directory, Emacs shows

```
No such file: <path/test.pdf>
```

in the echo area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution [using the org feature of adding new hyperlink types](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types). I can just create a new hyperlink type called `pdf`:

```
(org-add-link-type "pdf" 'org-mypdf-open)

(defcustom org-mypdf-command 'mypdf-open
  "The Emacs command to be used to display a pdf file."
  :group 'org-link)

(defun org-mypdf-open (path)
  "View the pdf file of PATH in evince."
  (funcall org-mypdf-command path))

(defun mypdf-open (path)
  (shell-command-to-string (concat "/home/hakon/my_org_pdf_viewer.sh " path)))
```

Then also change the script `/home/hakon/my_org_pdf_viewer.sh` to:

```
#! /bin/bash    
evince ~/my_pdf_files/"$1"
```

And `test.org` is now:

```
My sample org file. Here is an external link: pdf:test.pdf
```